# How to solve the Difference between Google Maps and Geocoding?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

OK here is an odd situation. This I have been facing from long time on so many Maps I have created.

Here is one sample address :

```
Hotel Tamisa Golf, Camino Viejo de Coín, 3, Mijas Costa, Málaga, 29649 , Spain
```

If we go to 
[maps.google.com](http://maps.google.com) 
and search this address, it comes to the exact Hotel Tamisa Golf.

But if we use Google Map's Geocoding method using this Example provided By Google themselves, and search this address over there, it is showing totally different location. Some miles away from actual location.

http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html

Is there a way to fix this so that is should show the Exact location on Map?

Answer (score 2):

That "address" is a "place" not a "postal address".

The geocoder finds the coordinates associated with a postal address, looks like it thinks the address is "Urbanización Mijas Golf, 13S, 29651 Mijas, Málaga, Spain":
[geocode](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Urbanizaci%C3%B3n%20Mijas%20Golf,%2013S,%2029651%20Mijas,%20M%C3%A1laga,%20Spain&geocode=1&type=m)

The [places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) finds "places": [place](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Hotel%20Tamisa%20Golf,%20Camino%20Viejo%20de%20Co%C3%ADn,%203,%20Mijas%20Costa,%20Spain&place=1)

Answer (score 0):

For the address you mentioned, the `geocode` is returning more than one results, you need to handle all the results. see your [answer here](http://jsfiddle.net/yaqubonnet/d5DBh/9/).

**EDIT**:
The `Google Place search API` can help you here, [for more detail see this](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#TextSearchRequests).
Sample example is here at [jsFiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaqubonnet/d5DBh/11/).

Comment: Neither of the results in that fiddle is correct.  Did you look at the results?

Comment: All the fiddles are invalid now.