# Google Distance Matrix distance differences with Google Map

Tags: google-maps, url

I am trying to get distance between below origin and destination using Google distance matrix url but i am getting distance as 9.2 km . Below are parameters & URL

```
origins=Fortis Medical Clinic, Sector 110, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201304
destinations=Domino's Pizza, C 2/22, Sector 18, Noida, UP 201301
mode=driving
```

Distance matrix URL 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=Fortis%20Medical%20Clinic,%20Sector%20110,%20Noida,%20Uttar%20Pradesh%20201304&destinations=Domino%27s%20Pizza,%20C%202/22,%20Sector%2018,%20Noida,%20UP%20201301&mode=driving

If i use google map to get distance for same address I get distance as 8.5 km. Below is URL
    https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/Fortis+Medical+Clinic,+Sector+110,+Noida,+Uttar+Pradesh+201304/Domino%27s+Pizza,+C+2%2F22,+Sector+18,+Noida,+UP+201301/@28.5472397,77.3183475,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x390ce8a50f230aad:0x62e94434495d1e29!2m2!1d77.387422!2d28.534182!1m5!1m1!1s0x390ce44932c98b67:0x54ee608ae1801238!2m2!1d77.324669!2d28.570486

Not sure why the difference of distance for same address.Does this happen for specific routes and why if so? OR any other reason.  Any Help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: sorry for the format as new to this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Domino's Pizza" and "Fortis Medical Clinic" are ["Places"](https://developers.google.com/places/) not addresses (look at the response from the DistanceMatrix to see how it is interpreting those strings).  To find the same distance reported by Google Maps, use the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/) to find their locations (coordinates), then use those in the DistanceMatrix call.

similar question: [How to solve the Difference between Google Maps and Geocoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546759/how-to-solve-the-difference-between-google-maps-and-geocoding/16547197#16547197)

DistanceMatrix response:

```
<DistanceMatrixResponse>
  <status>OK</status>
    <origin_address>Sector 110, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201304, India</origin_address>
    <destination_address>Sector 18, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201301, India</destination_address>
```

- Sector 110, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201304, India (28.5322238, 77.38340210000001)
- Sector 18, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201301, India (28.5688024, 77.32239149999998)

The Places API doesn't list "Fortis Medical Clinic" ( or at least have a different location for that), but it does for "Domino's Pizza" (which gives me the 8.5 km distance):

- Domino's Pizza, C 2/22, Sector 18, Noida, UP, India (28.570486, 77.32466899999997)

Comment: Fixed.Thanks a ton :-). Had to create API key and used Text Search Requests of Places API which returns me lat/long on passing the above origin and destination address in separate calls.Verified lat/long in google map which now gives 8.5 km. Got lat/long for origin as 28.5341820,77.3874220 by passing whole address "Fortis Medical Clinic, Sector 110, Noida, Uttar Pradesh 201304" and destination as 28.5704860,77.3246690 by passing address "Domino's Pizza, C 2/22, Sector 18, Noida, UP 201301" in XML response.

Comment: I had given the latitude and longitude directly in the request. Following are the requests:

Distance Matrix - http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=12.970392,77.591457&destinations=12.9584767,77.569559&mode=driving&language=en-EN

Google Maps - https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/'12.970392,77.591457'/'12.9584767,77.569559'/@12.9629888,77.5725415,15z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x0:0x0!2m2!1d77.591457!2d12.970392!1m5!1m1!1s0x0:0x0!2m2!1d77.569559!2d12.9584767!3e0?hl=en

The time in both the results vary. Are there any other parameters to be included?