# How do I get the correct address via the google maps api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So in a website I'm building I need to show a map with 2 markers on it, one marker where a certain painter was born and one where that same person died.

One of those places is Bedford Downs Station in Australia. Now when I type this into google I get the correct result: https://www.google.nl/maps?q=Bedford+Downs+Station,+Australia
, namely a place in Australia.

Now when I try to do the same thing on my website, using the google api, I only get locations in the US: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Bedford+Downs+Station,+Australia

WHY?

Comment: The google maps link is a "place" entry.  Possible duplicate of [How to solve the Difference between Google Maps and Geocoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546759/how-to-solve-the-difference-between-google-maps-and-geocoding/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Geocoding returning totally different result from Google Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436153/google-geocoding-returning-totally-different-result-from-google-map)

Answer (score 1):

I have use Google API to get latitude and logitude about address,
`

```
  public function latitudeLongitudeFromAdresse($address) {

    $coordinates = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' .urlencode($adresses).'&sensor=true');
    $coordinates = json_decode($coordinates);

    $latitude_longitude = array(
        "latitude" => $coordinates->results[0]->geometry->location->lat,
        'longitude' => $coordinates->results[0]->geometry->location->lng
    );

    return $latitude_longitude;
}
```

This function has always worked well, hope this help !